# OpenLDAP sync failing, claiming hasSubordinate value is invalid

Tags: openldap

2 OpenLDAP v2.4 nodes in mirrormode replication.

Getting this error:

```
syncrepl_message_to_entry: rid=001 DN: dc=example,dc=com, UUID: abc-123
syncrepl_message_to_entry: rid=001 mods check (hasSubordinates: value #0 invalid per syntax)
```

Both nodes log this, node #2 complains of rid=001 and node #1 complains of rid=002. The UUID and DN both match each other.
Both entries have `hasSubordinates: true` according to slapcat.

Node#2 was restored from a slapcat backup of Node#1. This was working in the past, but after repeating the conversion and import process from the old directory this is replacing, this started.

Answer (score 0):

I think just figured this out, it's due to my conversion.

`hasSubordinates` is an operational attribute that should not be imported. In my past imports I was not restoring the "dc=example,dc=com" entry because it already existed. However, on the day of deployment, I found deleting the entire directory contents with `ldapdelete` to be taking far too long (I'm guessing with replication and logging in place it is slower than in testing without). So I deleted the database file in `/var/lib/ldap` and restored the entire directory.